# Greasemonkey button click

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Can anyone please help me with clicking this button using greasemonkey?
http://mibpaste.com/te6fRR ([Full Source](http://www.erepublik.com/en))

Comment: Not a programming question...

Comment: It is not a button, just a link

Comment: @Jonathon Wisnoski: Ah, but on the actual page it might be styled to ***look*** like a button. ;)

Comment: It's not very helpful to post some viewsource-links, we need to be registered there and citizen of a specific country to see what you see there. I hope you don't assume we're start to play the game now to help you cheating.

Comment: I'm not going to cheat, but my friends are, and they wanted to stay incognito if someone playing erepublik sees this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var evt = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent ("click", true, true);
document.getElementById('fight_btn').dispatchEvent (evt);
```

See: http://wiki.greasespot.net/Generate_Click_Events

Comment: No!  That would generate an `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE` exception.
   I fixed it for you.

Comment: Really, I was trying to save 1 line ^^ . Thank's for fixing :)

Comment: I don't know why, but that doesn't click anything (or it clicks it, but nothing happens to button/link).

Comment: @user796738, the link, posted at mibpaste.com, doesn't do anything!  Post the full unedited page code, or -- better yet -- link to the actual target page.

Comment: @user796738, I created an account, found a mission and that "fight" button (that site is a pain, IMO).  Tested Dr.Molle's code, and it worked (started me fighting). I'm not to up on the finer points of that site (nor do I care to be).   Perhaps there's something else in your GM script?

Comment: @Brock Adams I tried to remove spaces between a word and a "(". It still doesn't work... any help?

Answer (score 4):

Since *`createEvent` and `initEvent` are now deprecated*, the following uses the new [`MouseEvent()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) instead:

```
document.getElementById("fight_btn").dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
```

You could use `getElementsByClassName("fight_btn")[0]` instead of `getElementById`, of course.